Customizing kcfinder configuration settings
Is there a way to modify kcfinder configuration settings other than by editing the kcfinder/conf/config.php file in the CiviCRM package tree?
I'm hoping for something similar to customizing CKEditor by putting settings in [Drupal base]/default/files/civicrm/persist/crm.ckeditor.civimail.js.  That way they don't get clobbered when I upgrade CiviCRM.
Specifically, I want to adjust the maxImageWidth and maxImageHeight values to limit the size of the images we include in bulk emails.
